# Java Observer Update function

Tags: java

I have a class that implements observer, and of course it needs to have the update function:

```
public void update(Observable obs, Object obj);
```

Can someone please explain what do the two parameters stand for?
Observable is my observable of course, but, how can I access my observable fields through this Observable obs object?
And what is Object obj?

Answer (score 7):

In case anybody else is experiencing difficulty in figuring out how to send that second parameter, it is as Nick points out:  In the **notifyObservers** method call.

**In the Observable:**

```
private void setLicenseValid(boolean licenseValid) {
    this.licenseValid = licenseValid;
    setChanged();  // update will only get called if this method is called
    notifyObservers(licenseValid);  // add parameter for 2nd param, else leave blank
}
```

**In the Observer:**

```
@Override
public void update(Observable obs, Object arg) {
    if (obs instanceof QlmLicense) {
        setValid((Boolean) arg);
    }
}
```

**Be sure to wire up your Observable correctly, else your update method will not get called.**

```
public class License implements Observer {  
    private static QlmLicense innerlicense; 
    private boolean valid;
    private Observable observable;

    private static QlmLicense getInnerlicense() {
        if (innerlicense == null) {
            innerlicense = new QlmLicense();
            // This is where we call the method to wire up the Observable.
            setObservable(innerlicense);  
        }
        return innerlicense;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    private void setValid(Boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
    }

    // This is where we wire up the Observable.
    private void setObservable(Observable observable) {
        this.observable = observable;
        this.observable.addObserver(this);  
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable obs, Object arg) {
        if (obs instanceof InnerIDQlmLicense) {
            setValid((Boolean) arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`obs` is the object that extends `Observable` and has the `notifyObservers` method. You can cast `obs` to your object that extends `Observable` and then call the methods you need.
`obj` is the optional parameter that can be passed to `notifyObservers`.

Comment: And there is no "danger" in casting obs to my extending class?

Comment: It depends. If you add your Observer only to one Observable it is save. If you add an Observer to multiple different Observables you can use the `instanceof` operator to check the type of `obs`.

Comment: Great. I have my observer only to one observable so casting would be fine I guess.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

The observer's update(Observable obs,Object obj) method receives through the notifyObservers  the object(second parameter) who has changed(in the Observable).