# Listener/Callback between android APP/Framework

Tags: android, callback, listener

I have an application and framework service, I would like to make a listener (As other topics, implement a interface(MyListener.java) as listener) to make framework service callback to application when some events happened.

But where should I put "MyListener.java" to make my framework service and application can import "MyListener.java"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I can't. But I use intent to communicate with application instead.

Comment: I ended up using Observer/Observable and that worked like a charm.  See q&a here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7271133/1735836

Comment: In fact, I'll give you the link to my question since @nana provided me with a very thorough explanation of options.  :)  See it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26871315/1735836

Comment: I just answered another question with details on how to implement the Observer and Observable here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26893836/1735836