# Android callback listener - send value from pojo in SDK to an application's activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, callback, listener

I have a java class buried deep in an SDK that performs an action and returns a boolean.  **It has no knowledge of the application's main activity**, but I need the main activity to receive that boolean value.

I've seen a lot of questions regarding callbacks, broadcasts, and listeners but they all seem to have knowledge of the activity.  My pojo does have an activityContext but I don't know how to get the value back to the application's main activity.

I'm already using an AsyncTask in my pojo and I'm trying to figure out how to send the boolean in the onPostExecute method in a way that the application's main activity can receive it.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You are able to change MainActivity code right ?

Comment: try this : https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus , you can even send the whole pojo itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I'd suggest using a message bus or observable/observer pattern**.

Square has [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) a nice little open-source library that implements a message bus.

Observer pattern is well described at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for example.

Either way what you will have to do is essentially start listening to either your POJO if you make it Observable, or subscribe for bus events in `onResume()` (or `onStart()`) and stop listening in `onPause()` in your activity.

## BUS

I like bus more because of it's loose coupling and the fact that you can send any arbitrary POJOs to the bus and only listen to one specific type for example.

so you post a message this:

```
bus.post(new SomethingICareAbout("I really really do"));
```

and elsewhere in your codebase (in your case in the activity):

```
@Subscribe
public void onSomethingIcareAbout(SomethingICareAbout thingsAndStuff) {
    // TODO: React to the event somehow. Use what you received.
}

@Subscribe
public void onSomethingElseIcareAbout(SomethingElseICareAbout otherThings) {
    // TODO: React to the event somehow. Use what you received.
}
```

The above is intentionally simplified, you still need to create the bus and subscribe to it, but you will find that in the docs :P
Also it uses annotations and is really lightweight (codewise).

## Observer / Observable

Observer/Observable on the other had is part of Java, so it's built in. But it is tightly coupled, your activity will have to implement Observer, your POJO will implement Observable and you willl have to implement update() method in your Activity, this one will get all the updates no matter what you send by the Observable.

*I hope this makes sense a bit :)*

Comment: I ended up using the Observer/Observable pattern...worked like a charm!  Thank you nana and codeMagic.  :)

Comment: Detailed information on implementing Observer/Observable can be found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26893836/1735836